# Showing previous array in picker view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i want to show particular array in picker view while i click textfield.I created two text field and two array with one pickerview.
i run my project success but fail when i select first textfield second array displaying in picker view and second textfield click its second array in picker view i don't want to second array in first textfield.

Picker view coding:

```
pktStatePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    pktStatePicker  .delegate = self;

    pktStatePicker  .dataSource = self;

    [ pktStatePicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

   txtText.inputView =  pktStatePicker  ;
    currency1.inputView = pktStatePicker;

    // Create done button in UIPickerView


    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];

    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];


    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];


    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];

    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


    txtText.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;
    currency1.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;

}
```

Picker view delegates and textfield:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == txtText )
    {
        pktStatePicker = arrMsg;
        [pktStatePicker reloadAllComponents];

    }
    else if (textField == currency1 )
    {
        pktStatePicker = currencyname1;
        [pktStatePicker reloadAllComponents];
    }

}
-(void)pickerDoneClicked

{
    NSLog(@"Done Clicked");


    [txtText resignFirstResponder];
    //[currency1 res];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

{

    return 1;

}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag == 1){
        return arrMsg.count;
    }else{
    return currencyname1.count;
    }
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag==1){

        return [arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
            return [currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }

}


- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag ==1){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    }else{
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }

}
```

Comment: which are your two array and its values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you set pktStatePicker.tag? By defaults it sets to zero, and you see second array every time. Add to you code

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (textField == txtText )
{
    pktStatePicker.tag = 1;


}
else if (textField == currency1 )
{
    pktStatePicker.tag = 0;

}
  [pktStatePicker reloadAllComponents];
return YES;
}
```

And delete

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField == txtText )
{
    pktStatePicker = arrMsg;


}
else if (textField == currency1 )
{
    pktStatePicker = currencyname1;

}

   [pktStatePicker reloadAllComponents];
```

}

It's wrong. I think It may help you. I didn't check

Comment: an error occur as "control reaches end of non void function"

Comment: I forgot "return YES;" in the end of the body of method

Comment: I have checked it. It's work. Do you set delegates to you UITextField's?

Comment: ya i set with picker view itself

Comment: txtText.delegate = self & currency1.delegate = self?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111208/discussion-between-a-sonu-and--).

Comment: i had an another dought if its three textfield means tag=3?

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

Declare a simple enum to manage picker states in the top of your .m file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUIInteger, PickerState) {
   PickerStateFirst = 0, 
   PickerStateSecond
}
```

Declare a PickerState variable:

```
@property (nonatomic) PickerState pickerState;
```

Set picker state when textfield begin editing by its tag(set it in IB):

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  self.pickerState = textField.tag;
  [pktStatePicker reloadAllComponents];
   return YES;
}
```

Check what state right now in pickers delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(self.pickerState == PickerStateFirst){
        return arrMsg.count;
    }
    return currencyname1.count;
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     if(self.pickerState == PickerStateFirst){
         return [arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
     } 
     return [currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row]; 
}


- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(self.pickerState == PickerStateFirst){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```